# Counting the factors of $2^4 \cdot 3^5 \cdot 4^6 \cdot 6^7$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Let $n = 2^4 \cdot 3^5 \cdot 4^6 \cdot 6^7$. How many natural-number factors does $n$ have?

I'm not quite sure how to go about solving this problem; there seems to be a lot of overcounting involved.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to count the number of times you use each prime. Because of the Fundamental theorem of arithmetic, you know that every natural number is encoded by how many powers of each prime are in it, so this procedure counts them all. So let's see, we have

$$2^4\cdot 3^5\cdot 2^{2\cdot 6}(2\cdot 3)^7=2^{23}\cdot 3^{12}$$

So we see the number of choices is

$$(23+1)\cdot (12+1)$$

Comment: The method seems correct, but $1680$ is not the correct answer...

Comment: This answer isn't right because you must use the prime factorization.

Comment: @Adam: it's wrong. You didn't prime factorize.

Comment: @symplectomorphic oops, duh. Good catch. Whenever I see factorizations I think they're prime. #numbertheoristproblems.

Answer (score 1):

The number $n$ has **prime power** factorization $n=2^{23}3^{12}$. Now use the counting idea suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Out of $n$ identical object, number of ways of choosing $k$ objects = 1 ( $k \leq 1)$

Treat the powers of a prime factor ( say $2^m$) as $m$ identical objects in a box numbered as $2$.